# Не понимаю как работает паттерн Декоратор

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Добрый день. Имеется код:

```
    public interface Car {
    public int getPrice();
    public String getDescription();
}

public class SimpleCar implements Car {

    @Override
    public int getPrice() {
        return 1000;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Simple auto";
    }
}

public abstract class CarDecorator implements Car {

    protected final Car car;

    public CarDecorator(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPrice() {
        return car.getPrice();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return car.getDescription();
    }
}

public class Conditioner extends CarDecorator {
    public Conditioner(Car car) {
        super(car);
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return car.getPrice() + 3000;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return car.getDescription() + " with conditioner";
    }
}
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car = new SimpleCar();
        System.out.println("Cost: " + car.getPrice() + " Description: " + car.getDescription());

        Car car1 = new Conditioner(car);
        System.out.println("Cost: " + car1.getPrice() + " Description: " + car1.getDescription());
    }
}
```

Объясните пожалуйста, туплю, но не пойму, как в классе Conditioner в строчке `return car.getPrice() + 3000;` получается 4000? Понимаю, что `car.getPrice()` само по себе возвращает 1000, но не пойму как так происходит..

Comment: Результат зависит от переданного в конструктор объекта `car`. Покажите код, который обращается к `Conditioner`, с помощью которого проверили, что получается 4000.

Comment: вот, добавил код

Answer (score 3):

Класс `Conditioner` расширяет `CarDecorator`, в котором есть атрибут `car` с областью видимости `protected` - т.е. он виден для классов-потомков.
При вызове метода `getPrice()` класса `Conditioner` вызывается метод `getPrice()` у атрибута `car` - экземпляра класса, реализующего интерфейс `Car`, который был передан в конструктор класса `Conditioner`. В вашем коде видна только одна реализация данного интерфейса -  `SimpleCar` (вы, вероятно, ее используете?), в ней метод возращает 1000. Итого 1000 + 3000 = 4000

**UPD** после добавления в вопрос кода:
То, что я написал выше справедливо для:

```
System.out.println("Cost: " + car1.getPrice() + " Description: " + car1.getDescription());
```

А здесь напрямую вызывается реализация методов `getPrice()` и `getDescription()` из класса `SimpleCar`:

```
System.out.println("Cost: " + car.getPrice() + " Description: " + car.getDescription());
```

Comment: да, вот добавил еще один класс, где объекты создаю